# How to get all Apigee request headers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, apigee

I have some JavaScript in which I need to work with all the request headers in Apigee. The online doc ( http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/javascript-object-model ) mentions them available via context.proxyRequest.headers as name/value pairs. Do I have to iterate through them, or are they available en masse as an array via context.proxyRequest.headers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the request headers through your javascript using something like below

```
var request_headers = context.getVariable("request.headers.names");
```

The scope of this variable is only within the proxy request flow.

Comment: Similarly you can get the values for each header using "request.header.{header_name}.values". You do not have to iterate through them.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me to examine all the request headers:

```
// reflectHeaders.js
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// formats the request headers into a JSON response.
//
// created: Tue May 13 11:42:19 2014
// last saved: <2014-May-13 12:05:39>

var requestHeaders = context.getVariable("request.headers.names"),
    result = {};

// requestHeaders is a java.util.TreeMap$KeySet; convert it to string
requestHeaders = requestHeaders + '';

// convert from "[A, B, C]" to an array of strings: ["A", "B", "C"]
requestHeaders = requestHeaders.slice(1, -1).split(', ');

// insert each header into the response
requestHeaders.forEach(function(x){
  var a = context.getVariable("request.header." + x );
  result[x] = a;
});

// set the response content:
context.setVariable('response.content', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

If you like, [here is a complete proxy bundle](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108815950/ex-js-header.zip) that shows how to use this JS. Just deploy it into an Apigee org and invoke it like this:

```
curl -H x-custom-header:my-custom-value http://ORG-ENV.apigee.net/v1/ex-js-header
```

output:

```
{
  "Accept": "*/*",
  "Host": "ORG-ENV.apigee.net",
  "User-Agent": "curl/7.30.0",
  "x-custom-header": "my-custom-value"
}
```